# Parallel/Concurrent http request sending from urllib2 in python

Tags: python, multithreading, http, httprequest, urllib2

I was trying to send out http post requests in parallel to a web service. To be specific, I'd like to do load test the web service under concurrent requests environment in terms of response time. So I plan to use thread and urllib2 to achieve the job - each thread carries out a http request by urllib2.

Here is how I did it:

```
import urllib2 as u2
import time
from threading import Thread

def run_job():
    try:
        req = u2.Request(
            url = **the web service url**,
            data = **data send to the web service**,
            headers = **http header web service requires**,
            )
        opener = u2.build_opener()
        u2.install_opener(opener)
        start_time = time.time()
        response = u2.urlopen(req, timeout = 60)
        end_time = time.time()
        html = response.read()
        code = response.code
        response.close()       
        if code == 200:
            print end_time - start_time
        else:
            print -1
    except Exception, e:
        print -2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 1
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        N = int(sys.argv[1])
    threads = []
    for i in range(1, N):
        t = Thread(target=run_job, args=())
        threads.append(t)
    [x.start() for x in threads]
    [x.join() for x in threads]
```

In the meantime, I use [fidller2](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the requests sending out. Fiddler is a tool to compose http request and send it out, and it can also capture the http requests through the host.

When I looked at the fidller2, those requests are sending out one by one instead of sending out all together at a time, which is what I expect to happen. If what represented in fiddler is right (requests are sending out one by one), to my knowledge, I think there must be some queue that the requests are waiting in. Could someone shed some light what happened behind this? And if it possible, how to do the real parallel requests?

Also, I have put two time stamps before and after the request takes place, if requests are waiting in queue after urllib2.urlopen is executed, then the delta of two time stamps includes the time spending in waiting queue. Is it possible to be more precise - to measure the time between request sending out and received?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Are you certain **Fiddler** can handle concurrent requests?

Comment: Also, why are you re-building and installing the opener in each thread? You don't use a custom opener stack, so why do that at all?

Comment: Hi Martjin, thanks for your response. For fiddler, I believe it can manage capturing concurrent requests - the first few requests, or may be 10 - 20 requests, are captured and displayed at the same time. And then I can see the requests are sent out one by one on fiddler. For the reason rebuild and install opener, the data in the request was changed from time to time.

Comment: You might want to check out siege (http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/). I did some load-testing using scrapy a few days ago and abandoned it in favor of siege.